# Ejecutar bloque del timer en segundo plano cuando se ejecute la aplicación en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollado una aplicación en C# con Windows Form, en si es un buscador en donde se conecta a la base de datos para que traiga datos y los ponga en un DataGridView , pero en dicha aplicación contiene un menúStrip en donde contiene tres módulos (cada uno esta en un Form) y obtiene información desde un archivo de Excel y la envía a una base de datos, tiene implementado un timer en el cual checa cada cierto tiempo el archivo para que lo envié a la base de datos 
Mi duda es como hacer que cuando se ejecute la aplicación también se ejecute los módulos para que este leyendo el archivo.
Se que con hilos lo puedo hacer pero no se me ocurre una forma de como hacer el intento, que me recomiendan?

Así es como lo estoy haciendo, este código es para el buscador, y ahi es donde pongo el hilo para que empiece a obtener los datos del otro formulario

```
public partial class Home : Form
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Threat t = new Thread (timer1_Tick_1);
        t.start();

    }
    //Tipos de Busquedas INICIO
    private void fechaBusqueda(String pFecha = null)
    {
        using (Models.plcModSegPasoEntities db = new Models.plcModSegPasoEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<DatosGetSet> lst =
                from d in db.plcModulesValues
                select new DatosGetSet
                {
                    horaA = d.Hora,
                    fechaA = d.Fecha,
                    moduloA = d.Modulo,
                    operadorA = d.Operador,
                    codeLlantaA = d.CodeLlanta,
                    numLlantaA = d.NumLlanta,
                    codeBarraA = d.CodeBarra,
                    construcTimeA = d.ConstrucTime,
                    timeCicloA = d.CicloTime
                };
            // Casos de busqueda 1
            if (pFecha != null) 
                lst = lst.Where(d => d.fechaA == pFecha);
            dGVDatos.DataSource = lst.ToList();
        }
    }
    //Tipos de Busquedas FIN
    //Evento del boton buscador INICIO

    private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtFecha.Text.Trim().Equals("") && txtModulo.Text.Trim().Equals("") && txtOperador.Text.Trim().Equals("") && txtCodigoLlanta.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
            fechaBusqueda(txtFecha.Text.Trim());
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontro ningún resultado con esa busqueda", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); // es como lo de 1 en flyair
    }
    //Evento del boton buscador FIN
    //Menu Strip para que abra los modulos en ventanas separadas INICIO
    private void moduToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form mod1 = new Mod1();
        mod1.Show();
    }

    private void salirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    //Menu Strip para que abra los modulos en ventanas separadas FIN
}
```

Este es el windows form el cual lee del excel y lo envia a la bd, el bloque que estoy haciendo que sea el hilo es `timer1_Tick_1`

```
public partial class Mod1 : Form
{
    public Mod1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //MisVariables
    DatosGetSet datos = new DatosGetSet();
    double modulo = 0, numLlanta = 0, timeConstruccion = 0, timeCiclo = 0;
    String operador = null, codigoLlanta = null, codigoBarras = null;
    String codBarAux = null, sqldate = null, sqltime = null;

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //El timer desde aqui enpieza
    {
        try
        {
            //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\N033321a\Desktop\modulos.xls");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            //Count of Raw and Columns in Excel
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            //R,C ExtraigoLosValoresDeCadaCelda
            sqldate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MM-yyyy");
            sqltime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
            modulo = (xlRange.Cells[40, 2] as Excel.Range).Value;
            operador = (xlRange.Cells[40, 3] as Excel.Range).Value;
            codigoLlanta = (xlRange.Cells[40, 4] as Excel.Range).Value;
            numLlanta = (xlRange.Cells[40, 5] as Excel.Range).Value;
            codigoBarras = (xlRange.Cells[40, 6] as Excel.Range).Value;
            timeConstruccion = (xlRange.Cells[40, 7] as Excel.Range).Value;
            timeCiclo = (xlRange.Cells[40, 8] as Excel.Range).Value;

            //DeLasVariablesLasPongoEnLosTextbox
            txtFecha.Text = sqldate + " " + sqltime;
            datos.fechaA = sqldate;
            datos.horaA = sqltime;

            txtModulo.Text = modulo.ToString();
            datos.moduloA = modulo.ToString();

            txtOperador.Text = operador.ToString();
            datos.operadorA = operador.ToString();

            txtCodLlanta.Text = codigoLlanta.ToString();
            datos.codeLlantaA = codigoLlanta.ToString();

            txtNumLlanta.Text = numLlanta.ToString();
            datos.numLlantaA = numLlanta.ToString();

            txtCodBarras.Text = codigoBarras.ToString();
            datos.codeBarraA = codigoBarras.ToString();

            txtTiempoConstr.Text = timeConstruccion.ToString();
            datos.construcTimeA = timeConstruccion.ToString();

            txtTiempoCiclo.Text = timeCiclo.ToString();
            datos.timeCicloA = timeCiclo.ToString();

            //Condicion para que no envie llantas repetidas a la BD
            if (!codigoBarras.Equals(codBarAux))
            {
                codBarAux = codigoBarras.ToString();
                DatosDAL.Agregar(datos);
            }

            //cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
            //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
            //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

            //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

            //La linea salvadora  <3
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            //close and release
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

            //quit and release
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Se produjo un error al leer el archivo de excel \n Error: " + ex.Message, "FATAL ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hola frank debes colocar código de lo que haz desarrollado asi es mas facil ayudarte, dices que tienes un excel y como trae los datos (el código) y como los graba en la bd?. esto es mejor cuando expones el código

Comment: se hace con hilos. Que intentaste?

Comment: Lo intente poniendolo en donde va el InitializeComponent(); del Form Home

Answer (score 0):

lo que entiendo es que cada vez que cambia el archivo en Excel tienes que actualizar tu base de datos. En vez de utilizar hilos o timers, te recomendaría utilizar la clase [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.6), esta clase "escucha" los cambios realizados en el sistema de archivos y genera eventos cuando cambia un directorio o un archivo de un directorio. De esa forma, te puedes enterar que el archivo ha cambiado, y lo puedes leer y actualizar tu base de datos. En el enlace hay un ejemplo que te podría aclarar el tema. 
Yo hice algo parecido para detectar que existia un archivo nuevo en una carpeta y enviarlo por FTP, que creo que es una tarea similar a la que tienes.

[Un ejemplo más similar puedes verlo aquí](http://gmoralescruz.blogspot.com/2009/05/inspeccionar-cambios-en-archivos-y.html). Esta página no es mía ni conozco al autor.